# How do I make one parenthesis not count toward the highlighting of matching brackets in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

What's happening now is this:

(**(**"hello :**)**"))

**(**("hello :)"**)**)

What I want to happen is this:

(**(**"hello :)"**)**)

**(**("hello :)")**)**

Again, this is in Notepad++. Is this even possible?

Comment: "Is this even possible?" I don't think so. Notepad++ doesn't understand smileys ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you go to "Language" and select a programming language that uses quote-encapsulation, Notepad++ will start processing this intelligently.

For example, selecting Java as the active language will cause the behavior you are looking for.